# Краш сервера TomCat при первом запуске нового проекта в IntelliJ

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

Всем доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. При создании нового проекта на Spring MVC при запуске сервера TomCat  выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
[2017-07-15 06:21:44,918] Artifact books:war exploded: Artifact is being 
deployed, please wait...
15-Jul-2017 18:21:45.125 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners 
failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log 
file
15-Jul-2017 18:21:45.126 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup 
failed due to previous errors
[2017-07-15 06:21:45,136] Artifact books:war exploded: Error during artifact 
deployment. See server log for details.
15-Jul-2017 18:21:54.728 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web 
application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.45\webapps\manager
15-Jul-2017 18:21:54.760 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web 
application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.45\webapps\manager has finished 
in 32 ms
```

**Дальше, в логах сервера пишет вот это:**

```
15-Jul-2017 19:08:26.453 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Error configuring 
application listener of class 
[org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

Ну и там дальше ещё много инфы.

Вроде весь спринг подгружен, не понимаю, почему не видит этот класс ContextLoaderListener.

**Вот скрины того, как я создаю проект.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И пошла подкачка spring-a.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Заранее большое спасибо за помощь!**

Comment: У вас там написано, что надо в лог сервера посмотреть

Comment: Добавил инфу с логов, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: Точно такая проблема,3 й день мучаюсь, без понятия что не так